# Androidx min sdk

Tags: android, androidx

What is androidx min sdk? I just migrated to androidx and i need to support minsdk 14. But my build fails indicating that androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0 has minsdk 15. 
I can't find it in release notes or anywhere else

Comment: I think google recommends minSdk 16. here's a link that I hope will shed some light on the situation. (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/google-ends-support-for-android-ice-cream-sandwich-api-levels-14-and-15/)[link]

Comment: Just a note. API14 is 4.0.0. API 15 is 4.0.3. I think that today doesn't exist a device with 4.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0 requires the minSdk = 15 ([see](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/browser/browser/1.0.0)) in order to function properly, so generally theres no way to support minSdk = 14 while still using androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0.

So basically you have these options:

*a.* Set minSdkVersion to 15 in app level build.gradle file(and stop supporting minSdkVersion 14)

**However if u 'must' have to support minSdkVersion 14 :**

*b.* You can add this line in AndroidManifest.xml file just before application tag:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.browser"/>
```

this will ensure the project will run properly in most cases but it might lead to run time crashes in few occasions.If you are not really using some feature of the class that absolutely requires sdkVersion 15 then u might just get lucky.

*c.* Look for alternative classes that can do similar behaviour with minSdkVersion 14 (this might be extremely unlikely)

*d.* You can consider reverting back to android support libraries instead of androidx. Since, android support libraries will continue to stay around in the google's maven repo for a while.

Answer (score 1):

[As stated here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library):

> Starting with Support Library release 26.0.0 (July 2017), the minimum supported API level across most support libraries has increased to Android 4.0 (API level 14) for most library packages.

AndroidX has started with the support library for API Level 28, so `minSdk 14` will be the requirement.

For your artifact, the current stable version [requires minSdk 15](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/browser/browser/1.0.0) and the current latest alpha release (1.2.0-alpha09) [requires minSdk 16](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/browser/browser/1.2.0-alpha09).

AndroidX browser is afaik a replacement / androidX version of Chrome Custom Tabs which had required minSdk 16, maybe this explains the sdk requirement.

By the way you can find the release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/browser).